# List categories of current taxonomy archive

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

[image]Here's my site: http://bmi.brownsmedicalimaging.com/product-category/c-arm/

I've created a custom post type called Products. Then I created 2 custom taxonomies, **Categories** and **Manufacturers**. If I'm viewing for example the "C-Arm" category page above, I have it displaying 2 posts from that category. How can I get it to display the list of manufacturers in that category? Right now it just outputs all the manufacturers I have defined. Here is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_cat_list', 'my_list_categories_shortcode' );
/**
 * this function outputs your category list where you
 * use the [my_cat_list] shortcode.
 */
function my_list_categories_shortcode() {
    $args = array( 
        'echo' =>   false,
        'taxonomy'   =>     'product-manufacturer',
        'title_li' => '',
    );
    return wp_list_categories( $args ); 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `list of manufacturers in that category`? How do you declare/define if a manufacturer is in a category?

Comment: @PhilF Thanks, I just added a photo. I've got a bunch of manufacturers and a bunch of product categories. Right now I've got 2 different manufacturers in the "C-Arm" category. I just want to list those two since they're the only ones within the C-Arm category. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not a huge thing to do, in general, but we should avoid unnecessary calls to the database and WordPress inherently doesn't provide us functionality like this. So I created my own custom sql query for performance reasons. See:

```php
function get_related_list_categories ($term_taxonomy_id, $related_taxonomy)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(term_taxonomy_id)
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships
            WHERE object_id IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID)
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships AS tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
                WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$term_taxonomy_id}) AND p.post_type = '{$post_type}' AND (p.post_status = 'publish')
              ) AND term_taxonomy_id IN (
                  SELECT term_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = '{$related_taxonomy}'
              )";

    if (empty($term_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql))) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $wp_list_categories(['include' => $term_ids, 'taxonomy' => $related_taxonomy, 'echo' => false, 'title_li' => '',]);
}

get_related_list_categories($product_category_id, 'product-manufacturer');
```

Again, I chose `product_category_id` as the first param (as opposed to the slug) since I figured it's most likely you'll have that and won't need to do a database call to get the slug. Either way, you can customize the function to your liking. I'm sure you'll have your own tweaks, like I return false on no terms found, but you may want to do it another way. Let me know if this works for you, or if you have any questions.

---

**UPDATE: Further explanation if needed for debugging.**

The sql query consists of two sub-queries.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID)
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_posts as p
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}_term_relationships as tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$term_taxonomy_id})
    AND p.post_type = '{$post_type}'
    AND (p.post_status = 'publish')
```

1. This finds all the posts that associated with the current term in question. It should match the post ids of that archive page. Run this query separate to test to see if the proper post ids are coming back. You can tweak the `WHERE` clause if you want to do it for multiple terms or by slug, etc.

```sql
SELECT term_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_term_taxonomy
WHERE taxonomy = 'related_experience'
```

2. The second sub query gets all the terms for the 'related_experience' taxonomy (or whatever secondary taxonomy you want). You should run this and verify all your term ids for 'related_experience' are coming back

Then the parent sql query joins the post ids from the first taxonomy and gets all the terms from the second taxonomy that ALSO show up in the posts that have the first taxonomy.

Comment: Wow thanks so much @Phil F for the code. I created a shortcode out of your function and dropped it into my template, but it doesn't seem to be working. It should be showing up between the two "new code" lines on this page: http://bmi.brownsmedicalimaging.com/product-category/c-arm/

Comment: It looks like there was a spot where I forgot to update a variable. I've updated that along with an additional explanation in my answer so you can debug or tweak what I have to fit your needs. Since I don't have all the terms/taxonomy information of your local instance, you'll have to run through the sql query and change the variables that may be different for you. If you're still seeing an issue, let me know if both sub-queries are returning the correct information and we can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks Phil, this code worked perfect! I really appreciated that you took the time to explain this! This was very helpful :)